# .sh files requires `sh app.sh` even with `#!/bin/bash` line

Tags: bash

I am under the impression that if I include the line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the start of my file, it will be recognized as a bash script that I can run just by

```
file.sh
```

instead of

```
sh file.sh
```

But in my case, `file.sh` gives something like `test.sh` gives `test.sh: command not found`. Why is that?

**UPDATE**

I notice I need to use `./`. But I thought it will look in the current directory anyway?

```
./test.sh
```

Comment: Did you include `\#!/bin/bash` in your file as you write? There shouldn't be a backslash in the beginning.

Comment: Nono thats a typo ... also see update

Comment: No, it doesn't work in the current directory unless, the current directory is in your PATH. You can edit your PATH to always include the current directory `.`, but it is not recommended.

Comment: `sh file.sh` and `./file.sh` are **not** equal if the first line is `#!/bin/bash`! The correct way to execute bash scripts is by using `bash file.sh`. Also, using the `.sh` extension is discouraged because of the confusion ("it says .sh, so I must use `sh file.sh` right?")

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to make sure the file is executable:

`chmod +x file.sh`

And then to run it, you either need to put it in your PATH, i.e., one of the directories of files the OS searches when looking for files to run, which you can find with `echo $PATH`, or else you need to type in:

`./file.sh`

Rather than just type `file.sh`.

You can just type `file.sh`, if it's in your PATH, which I recommend. A good place is in `~/bin`. Create that folder if it's not there, and under Ubuntu, it'll get added to your path when you log in.

Answer (score 5):

You need to start it with ./file.sh, because the current dir is not in the PATH.

If this isn't sufficient, becaused you missed, what frabjous suggests, to `chmod a+x`, you should start programs beginning with a shebang `#!/bin/bash` with

```
bash file.sh
```

not

```
sh file.sh
```

even if sh is a symbolic link to /bin/bash.

The shell checks how it was invoked, and can be invoked as `sh` to act in a compatible mode, therefore it can fail to handle some bashisms, which would work if invoked as `bash file.sh`.

That was not your problem, but might become one, if you don't know these subtle distinction.